# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 - possible to filter results grid?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

In SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I'm frequently writing a query, copying the results grid to Excel, and adding filters as I explore data.

Is there a way to filter the results grid from within SSMS? I'd prefer something that's built into the program, but a plugin would work. This appears to be a feature in some other programs like DbVisualizer and DataGrip, but I don't have a license of those.

EDIT: what I'm asking for is quick sorting and filtering of the result set in the same point-and-click way that I can sort and filter an Excel spreadsheet. I was thinking this would be more convenient and faster than adding additional clauses and conditions to queries.

If this still isn't a real question, I would not be opposed to a mod closing it, since I don't like the idea of a question floating out there that implies I don't know what a where clause is :-(

Comment: Yes. It's called a WHERE clause.

Comment: SSMS dont offer this feature. You could connect directly your database with excel and use some pivot table.

Comment: @gmsantos why wouldn't you just pivot inside of SSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for isn't a SSMS function. What you'd probably find valuable is a data visualization tool like tableau or spotfire. In addition to the graphical features they have a lot of grid features. Or, an SSIS to do some of the filtering and cleansing you need. Then you would t have to copy and paste every time.

Answer (score 0):

To filter the result set you have to use where clause.
For example result set query -

```
select firstName, lastName from employee
```

To filter it -

```
select firstName, lastName from employee
where lastName = 'abcd'
```